# data types: symbol vs enumerated?

Tags: c, types, enums, lisp, symbols

I wonder what differences and relations are between [symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_(programming)) and [enumerated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type) types?

I generated my question when reading in the first link for symbol type

> In the most trivial implementation, they (symbol types) are
>   essentially named integers (e.g. the enumerated type in C).

I followed the second link to read about enumerated type, but couldn't figure out their differences and relations.

For examples, they seem to exist in both Common Lisp [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_(programming)#Lisp) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type#Lisp), but my question is not limited to CL, neither do the two Wikipedia articles.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say we have a few text styles: `bold`, `ìtalic`, `thin`, `regular`. Now we have a function that draws some text:

```
(defun draw-text-string (text style stream)
   ...)
```

**Enumerations over integers**

How would we pass the the style information? We can encode them as numbers:

```
(defconstant +regular+ 0)
(defconstant +thin+    1)
(defconstant +bold+    2)
(defconstant +italic+  3)
```

We can encode them as bits:

```
(defconstant +regular+ #b0001) ; 1
(defconstant +thin+    #b0010) ; 2
(defconstant +bold+    #b0100) ; 4
(defconstant +italic+  #b1000) ; 8
```

Typically the *enumeration* type hides these mappings behind a type declaration.

When we call the drawing function, we pass these numbers in some way:

```
(draw-text-string "hello" +thin+ *standard-output*)
```

We could have written:

```
(draw-text-string "hello" 1 *standard-output*)
```

If we have the bit encoding, we can also pass a set:

```
(draw-text-string "hello" (logxor +thin+ +italic+) *standard-output*)
(draw-text-string "hello" 10                       *standard-output*)
```

The advantage is that the encoding is very compact. If we debug programs, in Lisp we would see numbers. In statically-typed languages the debugger can have access to the type information and could display the values as names.

This kind of enumeration is usually not done in Lisp - only if one needs to interface to external routines, typically following C conventions.

**Enumeration values as symbols**

In Lisp one can also use symbols for such a purpose. Either as single symbols or as lists of symbols. Here the symbols themselves are the values and they are not used as variables.

```
(draw-text-string "hello" 'thin *standard-output*)
(draw-text-string "hello" '(thin italic) *standard-output*)
```

In Common Lisp we often use self-evaluating keyword symbols. We then don't need to think about packages (namespaces).

```
(draw-text-string "hello" :thin *standard-output*)
(draw-text-string "hello" '(:thin :italic) *standard-output*)
```

The advantage for both is that we pass named objects around (symbols), which are easier to understand during debugging in a Lisp system. The drawback is that we may now pass lists of symbols, which is slightly less efficient that something like a number or bit vector.

Runtime type checking is then usually done via the [MEMBER](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/t_member.htm) type.

Answer (score 1):

Symbols can serve the purpose of an enumerated type, but symbols aren't really an enumerated type, unless you consider the set of all possible symbols (and, assuming that symbols can be infinitely long, then there are an infinite number of possible symbols) to be an enumeration.

The advantage of symbols, and the main way in which it's similar to enumerations, is that symbols are interned. So if you write `'foo` in one source file and `'foo` in another, they both evaluate to identical symbols (they will have the same object identity). This makes them ideal for use as hash keys, `case` expressions, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Chris! I wonder in C, how to define an object of symbol type?

Comment: You basically have to create an intern pool (basically a hash table), which you'd use for generating all symbols. Your symbol-generation function would take the symbol's name, look it up in the intern pool, and either add it if it doesn't exist, or return the existing instance in the intern pool. In either case, all symbols thus returned will reside in the intern pool.

Comment: One potential point of trouble is that most C programs don't employ garbage collection, and so your intern pool would only grow, and never shrink. This may or may not be problematic for you.

Comment: Once you have a suitable hash table implementation, an intern pool is really easy to implement. Here's Guava's implementation of it (in Java): https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Interners.java

Comment: (1) If I understand you correctly, in the hash table, a key is the name of "a variable of the symbol type", and the value for the key is a symbol and is the value taken by the variable? (2) Is the name of "a variable of the symbol type" again a symbol?

Comment: The key can be the string underlying the symbol, or can be the symbol instance itself; up to you. The value is the symbol instance. To answer your second question, the symbol's name is a string, which should be owned by the symbol object and not modifiable by other code. To ensure the symbol's ownership of the string, if you're _adding_ a symbol to the intern pool, you need to clone the underlying string so the caller doesn't have access to the symbol's backing string.